# Select field in CakePHP retrieve data

Tags: cakephp, select, field

I am trying to retrieve data from a simple table and populate a select field form. 
There are two tables, Acronyms and Topics.

Currently I have:
In my acronyms_controller (method add()):

```
$topics = $this->Acronym->Topic->find('list');
$this->set(compact('topics'));
```

In my acronym (model):

```
var $belongsTo = array(
        'Topic' => array(
            'className' => 'Topic',
            'foreignKey' => 'topic_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        )
    );
```

In my Topic model:

```
var $hasMany = array(
        'Acronym' => array(
            'className' => 'Acronym',
            'foreignKey' => 'topic_id',
            'dependent' => false,
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'exclusive' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'counterQuery' => ''
        )
    );
```

in my Acronym add view:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('topic_id'); ?>
```

I do not know why this is not working (it is not retrieving the Topic data in the select field). I download a simple application and did the same exercise and it did very well. I do not know what I am missing.

I would appreciate if I have your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your code all appears to be correct. If the topic name is not appearing in the select field, then it is probably because the field in the database table is not correct.

For Cake to automagically popular the select with a list of Topic names, there must be a field in your `Topic`table called `name`.

Otherwise, there must be something else in your controller conflicting with this, but I'd need to see the entire `add()` method to determine this.

Comment: There is a field named "name" in my table 'topics'. Here is my add(): function add() {
  
  $this->layout = 'default';
 
   if (!empty($this->data)) {
   $this->Acronym->create();
   if ($this->Acronym->save($this->data)) {
    $this->Session->setFlash('The acronym was deleted successfully.', 'flash_success');
    $this->redirect('/acronyms/add');
   } else {
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The acronym could not be saved. Please, try again.', true));
   }
   $topics = $this->Acronym->Topic->find('list');
   $this->set(compact('topics'));
  }
 }

Comment: Well, I still have no idea what happened. However, I got another similar code and just made some changes and, now, it is everything ok.

Thanks! 

I really appreciate Joseph and deceze.

Comment: That all looks ok, too. What exactly is the output in the view in terms of the HTML that is being generated by Cake for your $this->Form->input('topic_id'); ? Also, what is the result in the view if you add debug($topics); in the controller?

Comment: Thanks Joseph, as I said before, I solved the problem just copying and pasting a similar code of add() and every thing started to work. What pisses me off is that the code looks exactly the same. Who knows!?!